# MySQL row count in HTML select options fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a car database in which I have two tables, Makes and Models.

A typical Make row is:

```
(4, 'Alfa Romeo'),
```

A typical Models row is:

```
(35, 4, 'TwinSpark'),
```

On the HTML page, the select elements are propagated via the database, so when I choose Alfa Romeo (which in the db has 27 models), I would like to put in the option *Alfa Romeo (27)*.

How do I get the Models count into this element?

In my PHP I have this for the Makes:

```
<?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
```

On select this propagates the Models select which typically looks like this:

```
<select id="type" style="width: 212px;">
<option value="0">choose...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is this a SQL question (SELECT COUNT(*)) or something about some PHP DB framework?

Answer (score 2):

The following query should fetch the data you want from your database.

```sql
SELECT name, COUNT(id) AS count
FROM make, models
WHERE make.id = models.id
GROUP BY make.name
```

What you should do to output this, I can't tell you, since you haven't posted enough code/details.